# React Auth0 user isn’t authenticated after navigating from initial login

Tags: reactjs, auth0

I have a React app that uses the `auth0-react` package and the `useAuth0` hook. In my local environment that is using Auth0 dev keys, I can log in and out, and my session persists fine.

In my production instance, once I log in for the first time, I am able to access the user info. But if I try to navigate to another page or refresh, the user’s session is gone, and IsAuthenticated is false.

I have `useRefreshToken={true}` in my provider and refresh tokens active in my Auth0 dashboard. I have configured my Auth0 config for the app & Google Oauth to have my production URL as an allowed origin and the profile page as a callback URI. Cannot figure out why this is happening. I am using Chrome

```
  return (
    <Auth0Provider
      domain={domain}
      clientId={clientId}
      authorizationParams={{
        redirect_uri: redirectUri,
      }}
      useRefreshTokens
      onRedirectCallback={onRedirectCallback}
    >
      {children}
    </Auth0Provider>
  );
```

Login method

```
  const handleLogin = async () => {
    await loginWithRedirect({
      appState: {
        returnTo: "/profile",
      },
    });
  };
```

my navbar code that shows user on initial login, and gives undefined, false after navigating

```
  const { user, logout, isLoading, isAuthenticated} = useAuth0();

  console.log(user, isLoading);
```

I have tried changing my google ouath settings, using and not using refresh tokens, but nothing works for my production environment

Answer (score 1):

Figured this out, the issue was that my refresh token wasn't being stored. Adding `cacheLocation` to my Auth0Provider was the key

```
    <Auth0Provider
      domain={domain}
      clientId={clientId}
      authorizationParams={{
        redirect_uri: redirectUri,
      }}
      onRedirectCallback={onRedirectCallback}
      cacheLocation="localstorage"
      useRefreshTokens={true}
    >
      {children}
    </Auth0Provider>
```